# Telerik report Horizontal and vertical table border line issue

Tags: telerik, report, telerik-reporting

I am creating a report in Telerik reporting tool where the report should have a table with a horizontal border color (Gray) and vertical border color (white) with 3pt border width.

The problem I have is that the white line is getting overlap with some cut by the gray border of the table, but what I need is white line should overwrite gray line or we can say white line should be on the top of gray line.

Please find attached images for reference, 1st image I created but 2nd image is what I need to implement.

Thanks.

[image: actual.jpg]

[image: desired.jpg]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report Width="17cm" Name="demo" xmlns="http://schemas.telerik.com/reporting/2021/2.0">
  <Items>
    <PageHeaderSection Height="2cm" Name="pageHeaderSection1" />
    <DetailSection Height="5cm" Name="detailSection1">
      <Items>
        <Table Width="8.97cm" Height="1.718cm" Left="4cm" Top="1.9cm" Name="table1">
          <Body>
            <Cells>
              <TableCell RowIndex="0" ColumnIndex="0" RowSpan="1" ColumnSpan="1">
                <ReportItem>
                  <TextBox Width="2.99cm" Height="0.609cm" Left="0cm" Top="0cm" Value="1" Name="textBox2">
                    <Style BackgroundColor="Silver">
                      <BorderStyle Top="Solid" Bottom="Solid" Left="Solid" Right="Solid" />
                      <BorderColor Left="White" Right="White" />
                      <BorderWidth Left="3pt" Right="3pt" />
                    </Style>
                  </TextBox>
                </ReportItem>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell RowIndex="0" ColumnIndex="1" RowSpan="1" ColumnSpan="1">
                <ReportItem>
                  <TextBox Width="2.99cm" Height="0.609cm" Left="0cm" Top="0cm" Value="2" Name="textBox4">
                    <Style BackgroundColor="Silver">
                      <BorderStyle Top="Solid" Bottom="Solid" Left="Solid" Right="Solid" />
                      <BorderColor Left="White" Right="White" />
                      <BorderWidth Left="3pt" Right="3pt" />
                      <Padding Top="0cm" Bottom="0cm" />
                    </Style>
                  </TextBox>
                </ReportItem>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell RowIndex="0" ColumnIndex="2" RowSpan="1" ColumnSpan="1">
                <ReportItem>
                  <TextBox Width="2.99cm" Height="0.609cm" Left="0cm" Top="0cm" Value="3" Name="textBox6">
                    <Style Visible="True" BackgroundColor="Silver">
                      <BorderStyle Top="Solid" Bottom="Solid" Left="Solid" Right="Solid" />
                      <BorderColor Left="White" Right="White" />
                      <BorderWidth Left="3pt" Right="3pt" />
                    </Style>
                  </TextBox>
                </ReportItem>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell RowIndex="1" ColumnIndex="0" RowSpan="1" ColumnSpan="1">
                <ReportItem>
                  <TextBox Width="2.99cm" Height="0.5cm" Left="0cm" Top="0cm" Value="4" Name="textBox7" StyleName="">
                    <Style>
                      <BorderStyle Top="Solid" Bottom="Solid" Left="Solid" Right="Solid" />
                      <BorderColor Left="White" Right="White" />
                      <BorderWidth Left="3pt" Right="3pt" />
                    </Style>
                  </TextBox>
                </ReportItem>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell RowIndex="1" ColumnIndex="1" RowSpan="1" ColumnSpan="1">
                <ReportItem>
                  <TextBox Width="2.99cm" Height="0.5cm" Left="0cm" Top="0cm" Value="5" Name="textBox8" StyleName="">
                    <Style>
                      <BorderStyle Top="Solid" Bottom="Solid" Left="Solid" Right="Solid" />
                      <BorderColor Left="White" Right="White" />
                      <BorderWidth Left="3pt" Right="3pt" />
                    </Style>
                  </TextBox>
                </ReportItem>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell RowIndex="1" ColumnIndex="2" RowSpan="1" ColumnSpan="1">
                <ReportItem>
                  <TextBox Width="2.99cm" Height="0.5cm" Left="0cm" Top="0cm" Value="6" Name="textBox9" StyleName="">
                    <Style>
                      <BorderStyle Top="Solid" Bottom="Solid" Left="Solid" Right="Solid" />
                      <BorderColor Left="White" Right="White" />
                      <BorderWidth Left="3pt" Right="3pt" />
                    </Style>
                  </TextBox>
                </ReportItem>
              </TableCell>
            </Cells>
            <Columns>
              <Column Width="2.99cm" />
              <Column Width="2.99cm" />
              <Column Width="2.99cm" />
            </Columns>
            <Rows>
              <Row Height="0.609cm" />
              <Row Height="0.5cm" />
            </Rows>
          </Body>
          <Corner />
          <RowGroups>
            <TableGroup Name="detailTableGroup">
              <ChildGroups>
                <TableGroup Name="group" />
                <TableGroup Name="group1" />
              </ChildGroups>
              <Groupings>
                <Grouping />
              </Groupings>
            </TableGroup>
          </RowGroups>
          <ColumnGroups>
            <TableGroup Name="tableGroup">
              <ReportItem>
                <TextBox Width="2.99cm" Height="0.609cm" Left="0cm" Top="0cm" Value="A" Name="textBox1">
                  <Style>
                    <BorderStyle Top="Solid" Bottom="Solid" Left="Solid" Right="Solid" />
                    <BorderColor Left="White" Right="White" />
                    <BorderWidth Left="3pt" Right="3pt" />
                  </Style>
                </TextBox>
              </ReportItem>
            </TableGroup>
            <TableGroup Name="tableGroup1">
              <ReportItem>
                <TextBox Width="2.99cm" Height="0.609cm" Left="0cm" Top="0cm" Value="B" Name="textBox3">
                  <Style>
                    <BorderStyle Top="Solid" Bottom="Solid" Left="Solid" Right="Solid" />
                    <BorderColor Left="White" Right="White" />
                    <BorderWidth Left="3pt" Right="3pt" />
                  </Style>
                </TextBox>
              </ReportItem>
            </TableGroup>
            <TableGroup Name="tableGroup2">
              <ReportItem>
                <TextBox Width="2.99cm" Height="0.609cm" Left="0cm" Top="0cm" Value="C" Name="textBox5">
                  <Style>
                    <BorderStyle Top="Solid" Bottom="Solid" Left="Solid" Right="Solid" />
                    <BorderColor Left="White" Right="White" />
                    <BorderWidth Left="3pt" Right="3pt" />
                  </Style>
                </TextBox>
              </ReportItem>
            </TableGroup>
          </ColumnGroups>
        </Table>
      </Items>
    </DetailSection>
    <PageFooterSection Height="2cm" Name="pageFooterSection1" />
  </Items>
  <PageSettings PaperKind="A4" Landscape="False">
    <Margins>
      <MarginsU Left="2cm" Right="2cm" Top="2cm" Bottom="2cm" />
    </Margins>
  </PageSettings>
  <StyleSheet>
    <StyleRule>
      <Style>
        <Padding Left="2pt" Right="2pt" />
      </Style>
      <Selectors>
        <TypeSelector Type="TextItemBase" />
        <TypeSelector Type="HtmlTextBox" />
      </Selectors>
    </StyleRule>
  </StyleSheet>
</Report>
```

Comment: Is this reproducible when you export the document to PDF, or only in design-time?

Comment: this problem is coming in both design time as well as in pdf. 1st Attached images I cropped from pdf only after exporting and 2nd image I designed in MS Paint :)

Comment: Well without the report is it hard to tell, can you post a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: You can save the report as trdx and paste the xml.

Comment: XML was too long for comment so added in question.